# Hourly data loading from AWS S3 to Google Big Query

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery, pipeline

Currently, I have a data flow set up like below

AWS S3 (csv format) -> Data Transfer Service (once a day) -> Google Big Query

However, I would like to change the rate of data transfer, but since transfer service doesn't offer that I would have to implement my own methods.

What would be your recommendations? (Currently, I am thinking of just using AWS sdk to get the objects and then insert them using Google big query client, but I haven't tried it yet, and due to lack of my understanding I don't know if that's even possible or scalable... give me a hint or recommendations. Thank you)

Comment: Writing aws lambda using javascript or python bigquery lib is definitely a good option. Just make sure to manage your limits so you won't miss records. After you try this if you have a more specific question open a new question as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If there are some limitations that you can not change in Data Transfer I would advice you using `python` with AWS SDK and Google Cloud Library for reading from S3 and writing in BigQuery respectively. You can find these libraries in other languages though.

I also would advice you to use some serverless architecture for that. In `GCP` you could use `Cloud Function` for that if your transfer lasts less than **9 minutes** (This is a Cloud Function limitation). In `AWS` you could use `Lambda Function` if your transfer lasts less than **15 minutes**

If your transfer needs more time, you could use a VM in Compute Engine for that. In this case you could also use Cloud Schedule to turn on and turn off your VM in the exactly time you want. You can find the tutorial for that [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule)

Feel free to provide some extra information if you have any question.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is basically what I did except there were some major issues , but your description is correct. Anyways Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

The most cost-effective way to get data to BigQuery when at most a few min delay is acceptable would be using an event-driven serverless architecture.

You can write simple transfer and loader with lambda and cloud function or you can use some open-source projects like

- [StorageMirror](https://github.com/viant/smirror): s3 to GCS data mirror
- [BqTail](https://github.com/viant/bqtail): Google Storage based BigQuery loader